# windows phone keep running application background

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-cordova

I want to keep my application running in background (after push back). I tried to handle/implement WMAppManifest.xml (backgroundagent...) for that purpose but it doesn't work. Is it the only way to do that?

My application use geolocation and make requests to a server. Is it more complicate?

Thanks!

Comment: Which App you are created windows phone 8, windows phone 8.1 or windows phone 8.1 Silverlight ?

Comment: I think windows phone 8.1 (i have a lumia 435). If it s possible and not very complicate to have an high compatibility with others OS windows phone versions

Comment: Somebody have any ideas ??